# How to use arrayfomula to conver a image link to image thumbnails?

Tags: google-sheets

eg, if i have a column A with all image link from row 1 to 5.
How can i convert images to thumbnails preview in column from row 1 to 5？

Answer (score 1):

If your URLs are on the first column (A2:A), then on B2 write

```
=ArrayFormula(IMAGE(A2:A))
```

See [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hYODLLIKtsg9P2YkXZwUcA764dx4kxKsbtTw2t5lJn8/edit?usp=sharing) example